# Grammar that accepts the language: {a^i b^j c^i : i, j >= 1, j /= i}?

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar

What would be the context free grammar that accepts the language of strings of 'a,b,c' where the number of occurrences of 'a' match 'c' and b shows an arbitrary amount of times but cannot match the occurrences of 'a' and 'c'.

ie: L( {a^i b^j c^i : i, j >= 1, j /= i} )

---

EDIT TO COMMENTS: @Vladp this doesn't look right at all

[image]

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. This is CS theory. Try http://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: @MarcB I seen many CS theory questions similar to this on SO

Comment: Can I migrate this question?

Comment: @BDillan it doesn't make it right, but here is what you are looking for [B->bB,
B->b,
S->aSc,
S->B]

Comment: I agree that @Vladp propossed solution is wrong, but not because of the sample you give.. In the sample I don't see why Vladps should not work. I mean, apply 3 times S-> aSc, then S->B, then B->b. The reason why I think Vladps solution is wrong, because it does not enforce j /= i. Derivation of abc is really easy: S, aSc, aBc, abc. Should not be allowed.

Comment: the language you described it not context free grammar, easy proof using the pumping lemma.
if that was a homework question were there a disproof option of find only?

Comment: @Vladp, I've been playing around a bit and it seems that this is indeed not a context-free language. :-)